# Error al cargar imagen desde path con BufferedInputStream

Tags: java, android, ftp

Buen dia, estoy tratando de enviar una imagen desde JAVA- ANDROID a un servidor mediante ftp, este es el codigo que estoy utilizando dentro de una tarea asincrona

```
 try {

            FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
            ftpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName("ftp.miweb.com.co"));
            ftpClient.login("app_admin@miweb.com.co", "miclave");

            ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("/micarpeta");
            ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            BufferedInputStream buffIn = null;
            buffIn = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("/storage/8ABF-1303/Download (1)/soda_stereo_03.jpeg"));
            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            ftpClient.storeFile("foto.jpg", buffIn);

            buffIn.close();
            ftpClient.logout();
            ftpClient.disconnect();

        } catch (Exception s) {
            Log.i("consola", "Ups...");
            return "false";
        }
```

El problema esta en esta linea, al tratar de cargar la imagen desde el Uri

```
buffIn = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("/storage/8ABF-1303/Download (1)/soda_stereo_03.jpeg"));
```

Me arroja el siguiente error en el LOGCAT:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/8ABF-1303/Download (1)/soda_stereo_03.jpeg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Al final dice permiso denegado, estos son mis permisos del manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" 
android:required="false">
</uses-feature>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Ya investigue un buen rato y no he encontrado mucho al respecto, espero me puedan ayudar, gracias

Este es el tutorial del que me guié:
http://androcode.es/2012/05/apache-commons-ftp-subiendo-archivos-a-servidores/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aunque el mensaje de error indica `FileNotFoundException`, en realidad es problema de permisos:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/8ABF-1303/Download
>   (1)/soda_stereo_03.jpeg: open failed: EACCES **(Permission denied)**

Debes usar:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

en lugar de :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Al requerir el permiso `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` no es necesaria la petición de `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

---

Recuerda que para dispositivos con Android 6.0 o posterior, esta petición debe ser manual, agrego este método que puede ser de ayuda.

```
private void checkExternalStoragePermission() {
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para leer.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
    } else {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso para leer!");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Gracias tenias razón, tenia que agregar el permiso y el aviso para que el usuario lo acepte.

Comment: @AlvaroFabianM Excelente Alvaro, saludos!